# JustDecompile: Where do I find System.Runtime 5.0.0.0 location?

Tags: telerik

JustDecompile prompts me the following:

[image]

I have downloaded dotnet-sdk-5.0.100-win-x64.exe, but it still does not show up.

[image]

Where could I download what JustDecompile wants from me, or what else might be the problem here?

Edit:
I have now downloaded, but I still don't still what exactely I have to choose. I asks for a "location", but then again, the file dialog filter demands an exe or dll:

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Where could I download what JustDecompile wants from me, or what else might be the problem here?
>
> Edit: I have now downloaded, but I still don't still what exactely I have to choose. I asks for a "location", but then again, the file dialog filter demands an exe or dll:

What you need is the correct version of the .NET runtime - in this case, that's .NET 5. Downloading the .NET SDK works too as the SDK includes the runtime. It can be downloaded from the [official website](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download).

Theoretically, after the runtime is installed JustDecompile should be able to find it automatically. Sadly, JustDecompile seems to be abandoned as it hasn't received any meaningful updates since 2017. So you have to provide it manually. The assembly is located at `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\5.0.x\System.Runtime.dll`. Note that you should replace `5.0.x` with the correct version of the runtime which in your case is `5.0.100`.

To avoid having to manually provide the assembly you can use [CodemerxDecompile](https://decompiler.codemerx.com). It's the spiritual successor to JustDecompile, built on an improved version of the same engine with support for the latest frameworks and features.

*Disclosure: I'm part of the team behind CodemerxDecompile.*